# Find all regions within 400km for each region in list

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table called `Region`

`id | name | lat | lng`

I have a list of region id I want to search like

`(48346, 48335, 48325, 48324)`

For each region id above, I want to search region within 400km which can be done using (the following works for one region search and will return a list of regions within 400km of the chosen region):

```
// find region within 400km

SELECT id, (6371 * 
                    ACOS(COS(RADIANS(lat)) * 
                    COS(RADIANS(center_lat)) * 
                    COS(RADIANS(lng) - 
                    RADIANS(center_lng)) + 
                    SIN(RADIANS(center_lat)) * 
                    SIN(RADIANS(lat)))) AS distance
FROM
    region
WHERE
    active = 1
HAVING distance <= 400;
```

My problem is, currently I'm running PHP loop through the region list `(48346, 48335, 48325, 48324)` and for each id call the query to find region within 400km (after the loop, 4 lists of regions returned)

Is there a way to use one SQL query to find all regions `IN (48346, 48335, 48325, 48324);` and for each region find all regions within 400km of each region in the list

Comment: The query will return all `id` and `distance` from `region` table that are with `<=400` km. So why are you looping?

Comment: @KaranDesai I have a list of 20 cites, for each city I want a list of cities that within 400km, that's like 20 lists of cities.

Comment: not sure if MySQL can use the same functions as SQL server, but check the question i asked a while back, you could simply use the same function then filter down to 400km     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45483254/calculate-distance-between-points-using-long-and-lat-in-sql-server/45483494#45483494