# SQL - Find locations based on miles around zip code

Tags: sql, sql-server, geolocation

I have the below table structure

[image]

So my requirement is when I enter a zipcode, I want to find the shops 5 miles around the zipcode. Is there a way to do that? Not sure where to start. any help?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/spatial-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: A good place to start is to post sample data as text and not an image.  You could also take a peek at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45483254/calculate-distance-between-points-using-long-and-lat-in-sql-server/45483494#45483494

Comment: Do you have your zip codes defined in the database either as a point (e.g. the center of each zip code) or as a polygon?

Comment: @BenThul I have them defined as the center of each zip code. It looks as I added a pic above

Comment: Since you have lat and long of each location the zip code is likely irrelevant. Look at the link above from Gordon. The query for this is really straight forward.

Comment: Do you really have only 4 characters of each zip code?

Comment: @SeanLange - My guess is that they're being stored as numeric data types but these ones have a leading `0`.

Comment: @Rick - that wasn't obvious to me. As I look at your data, it looks to me like this is data about the stores, properties of which are the ZIP code, and lat/long of the store. Are those rows also meant to represent the ZIP codes as a whole?